# Laravel 4 not passing session value from controller to view

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I had a controller and in it I am storing a session value like this

```
if(!Session::isStarted())
   Session::start();
}
Session::put('total', $total);
```

In the view I'm trying to retrieve this value:

```
if(!Session::isStarted()){
    Session::start();
}
var_dump(Session::all());  // <-- value 'total' not showing
```

This is the output of the session

```
array(2) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "IzsMtiTOfMpoOzLj53YyMYEMAUHr4mLMnIAWcnaJ" ["flash"]=> array(2) { ["old"]=> array(0) { } ["new"]=> array(0) { } } }
```

Comment: What session driver are you using?

Comment: I already solved!, I just needed to put Session::save() (I'm using file driver)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use this:

```
if(!Session::isStarted())
    Session::start();
}
```

The `session` will be started by framework, you can simply use this:

```
Session::put('total', $total);
```

All you need to configure/set the `driver` in `app/config/session.php` file and by default `Laravel` uses `file` driver, it is set in the `app/config/session.php` like this:

```
'driver' => 'file',
```

> Laravel 4 not passing session value from controller to view

Actually you don't need to pass the session, if you set the `session` anywhere in your application then it'll be available in anywhere through your application, you can access it from your `view`, you don't need to pass it but you have to set/put the value in the session before you access it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the only thing I was missing is to save the session data like Session::save()

Comment: Welcome :-) Btw, I think you need to read the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/session) and also if you have confusing about session in `PHP` then you should read the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).

Comment: Yes I check the documentation but it says nothing about the save() method.

Comment: It's because that is not required by a `end user` We don't need to start or stop it, it's framework's responsibility, we just need to tell which driver we want to use.

Comment: I'm talking about the save method not Session::start()

Comment: They are unrelated, you just need `Session::put()` once and `Session::get()` from there onwards. Please accept the answer.